# the trait bound `<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId: pallet::Config` is not satisfied

Tags: pallet, storage

I'm trying to design a custom pallet with bounded vectors, but I want to leave the user to define the size of the bounds according to their implementation, so I use the next type:

```
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config + pallet_aura::Config {
        ...
        
        #[pallet::constant]
        type MaxDelegations: Get<u32>;
        #[pallet::constant]
        type MaxAuthorities: Get<u32>;
    }
```

And I use them in the next struct:

```
    pub struct DelegatorConfig<T: Config, AccountId, Balance> {
        pub is_validator: bool,
        pub delegated_points: Balance,
        pub delegates: BoundedVec<(AccountId, Balance), T::MaxDelegations>,
    }
```

And this storage

```
#[pallet::storage]
    pub type Delegators<T: Config> = StorageMap<
        _,
        Blake2_128Concat,
        T::AccountId,
        DelegatorConfig<T::AccountId, BalanceOf<T>, T::MaxDelegations>,
    >;
```

But now the compilers sends me this error message, what didn't happen when I just used  `Const<U32>`  for the bound. Any idea what I am missing?
I'm pasting the full code next:

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

/// Edit this file to define custom logic or remove it if it is not needed.
/// Learn more about FRAME and the core library of Substrate FRAME pallets:
/// <https://docs.substrate.io/reference/frame-pallets/>
pub use pallet::*;

#[cfg(test)]
mod mock;

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests;

#[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
mod benchmarking;

#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet {
    use super::*;
    use frame_support::bounded_vec;
    use frame_support::pallet_prelude::DispatchResult;
    use frame_support::traits::tokens::Balance;
    use frame_support::traits::{LockIdentifier, WithdrawReasons};
    use frame_support::{
        pallet_prelude::*,
        traits::{Currency, FindAuthor, LockableCurrency, ReservableCurrency},
    };
    use frame_system::pallet_prelude::{OriginFor, *};
    use sp_consensus_aura::{Slot, AURA_ENGINE_ID};
    use sp_runtime::traits::Convert;
    use sp_runtime::traits::{CheckedAdd, CheckedSub};

    pub type BalanceOf<T> =
        <<T as Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance;

    const LOCK_ID: LockIdentifier = *b"1       ";

    #[pallet::pallet]
    #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
    pub struct Pallet<T>(_);

    /// Configure the pallet by specifying the parameters and types on which it depends.
    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config + pallet_aura::Config {
        /// Because this pallet emits events, it depends on the runtime's definition of an event.
        type RuntimeEvent: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::RuntimeEvent>;

        /// Type to access the Balances Pallet.
        type Currency: Currency<Self::AccountId>
            + ReservableCurrency<Self::AccountId>
            + LockableCurrency<Self::AccountId>;

        /// A conversion function which takes an authority id, and returns the associated account id.
        type AuthorityToAccount: Convert<Self::AuthorityId, Self::AccountId>;

        type ValidatorBond: Get<BalanceOf<Self>>;
        
        #[pallet::constant]
        type MaxDelegations: Get<u32>;
        #[pallet::constant]
        type MaxAuthorities: Get<u32>;
    }

    // Pallets use events to inform users when important changes are made.
    // https://docs.substrate.io/main-docs/build/events-errors/
    #[pallet::event]
    #[pallet::generate_deposit(pub(super) fn deposit_event)]
    pub enum Event<T: Config> {}

    // Errors inform users that something went wrong.
    #[pallet::error]
    pub enum Error<T> {
        /// Too many authorities for Aura's limits.
        TooManyAuthorities,
    }

    #[derive(Encode, Decode, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen, Debug, Eq, PartialEq, Clone)]
    pub struct ValidatorConfig<T: Config, AccountId, Balance> {
        pub is_active: bool,
        pub points: Balance,
        pub delegators: BoundedVec<(AccountId, Balance), T::MaxDelegations>,
    }

    #[derive(Encode, Decode, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen, Debug, Eq, PartialEq, Clone)]
    pub struct DelegatorConfig<T: Config, AccountId, Balance> {
        pub is_validator: bool,
        pub delegated_points: Balance,
        pub delegates: BoundedVec<(AccountId, Balance), T::MaxDelegations>,
    }

    #[derive(
        Default, Clone, Encode, Decode, RuntimeDebug, PartialEq, Eq, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen,
    )]
    pub struct TotalStake<Balance> {
        pub validators: Balance,
    }

    #[derive(Encode, Decode, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen, Debug, Eq, PartialEq, Clone)]
    pub struct Candidates<T: Config, AccountId, Balance> {
        pub authorities: BoundedVec<(AccountId, Balance),  <T as pallet::Config>::MaxAuthorities>,
    }

    #[pallet::storage]
    pub type Validators<T: Config> = StorageMap<
        _,
        Blake2_128Concat,
        T::AccountId,
        ValidatorConfig<T::AccountId, BalanceOf<T>, T::MaxDelegations>,
    >;

    #[pallet::storage]
    pub type Delegators<T: Config> = StorageMap<
        _,
        Blake2_128Concat,
        T::AccountId,
        DelegatorConfig<T::AccountId, BalanceOf<T>, T::MaxDelegations>,
    >;

    #[pallet::storage]
    pub type StakePool<T: Config> = StorageValue<_, TotalStake<BalanceOf<T>>, ValueQuery>;

    #[pallet::storage]
    pub type EnabledAuthorities<T: Config> =
        StorageValue<_, Candidates<T::AccountId, BalanceOf<T>,  <T as pallet::Config>::MaxAuthorities>, OptionQuery>;

    // Dispatchable functions allows users to interact with the pallet and invoke state changes.
    // These functions materialize as "extrinsics", which are often compared to transactions.
    // Dispatchable functions must be annotated with a weight and must return a DispatchResult.
    #[pallet::call]
    impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
        /// An example of directly updating the authorities for Aura.
        #[pallet::call_index(0)]
        #[pallet::weight(0)]
        pub fn force_change_authorities(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            who: T::AuthorityId,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            ensure_root(origin)?;
            let mut authorities = BoundedVec::<T::AuthorityId, T::MaxAuthorities>::default();
            authorities.try_push(who).map_err(|_| Error::<T>::TooManyAuthorities)?;
            pallet_aura::Pallet::<T>::change_authorities(authorities);
            Ok(())
        }

        #[pallet::call_index(1)]
        #[pallet::weight(0)]
        pub fn register_validator(origin: OriginFor<T>) -> DispatchResult {
            let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;

            let default_config = ValidatorConfig {
                is_active: true,
                points: Default::default(),
                delegators: bounded_vec![],
            };

            // reserve some balance from the user
            T::Currency::reserve(&who, T::ValidatorBond::get())?;

            Validators::<T>::insert(who.clone(), default_config);
            Pallet::<T>::check_candidate(who);

            Ok(())
        }

        #[pallet::call_index(2)]
        #[pallet::weight(0)]
        pub fn delegate(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            validator: T::AccountId,
            new_amount: BalanceOf<T>,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            // THERE ARE ERRORS HERE. DONT USE DIRECTLY. THINK ABOUT MULTI DELEGATION SCENARIO

            let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
            let amount = new_amount.clone();
            let mut validator_config = Validators::<T>::get(&validator).ok_or("not a validator")?;

            let mut delegator_config;

            if Delegators::<T>::get(&who).is_some() {
                delegator_config = Delegators::<T>::get(&who).unwrap();
            } else {
                Pallet::<T>::register_delegator(who.clone());
                delegator_config = Delegators::<T>::get(&who).unwrap();
            }

            let new_delegation_amount =
                delegator_config.delegated_points.checked_add(&new_amount).unwrap();

            ensure!(T::Currency::free_balance(&who) >= new_amount, "not enough funds");
            T::Currency::set_lock(LOCK_ID, &who, new_amount, WithdrawReasons::all());

            ensure!(!validator_config.delegators.is_full(), "overflow");

            let pos_val = validator_config.delegators.iter().position(|(x, _)| x == &who);
            delegator_config.delegated_points = new_delegation_amount;
            validator_config.points += amount;
            if pos_val != None {
                validator_config.delegators[pos_val.unwrap()].1 += amount;
            } else {
                validator_config.delegators.try_push((who.clone(), amount));
            }
            let pos_del = delegator_config.delegates.iter().position(|(x, _)| x == &validator);
            if pos_del != None {
                delegator_config.delegates[pos_del.unwrap()].1 += amount;
            } else {
                delegator_config.delegates.try_push((validator.clone(), amount));
            }

            if Validators::<T>::contains_key(validator.clone()) {
                Validators::<T>::remove(validator.clone());
                Validators::<T>::insert(validator.clone(), validator_config);
            } else {
                Validators::<T>::insert(validator.clone(), validator_config);
            }

            if Delegators::<T>::contains_key(who.clone()) {
                Delegators::<T>::remove(who.clone());
                Delegators::<T>::insert(who.clone(), delegator_config);
            } else {
                Delegators::<T>::insert(who.clone(), delegator_config);
            }

            Pallet::<T>::increase_stake(amount);

            Pallet::<T>::check_candidate(validator);

            Ok(())
        }

        #[pallet::call_index(3)]
        #[pallet::weight(0)]
        pub fn revoke_delegate(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            validator: T::AccountId,
            amount: BalanceOf<T>,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
            let other_who = who.clone();
            let mut validator_config = Validators::<T>::get(&validator).ok_or("not a validator")?;

            let mut delegator_config = Delegators::<T>::get(&who).unwrap();

            ensure!(
                !(validator_config.delegators.iter().find(|(x, _)| x == &who) == None),
                "not a delegator of the current validator"
            );
            let pos_val = validator_config.delegators.iter().position(|(x, _)| x == &who).unwrap();
            let validator_points = validator_config.points;
            let validator_delegator_points = validator_config.delegators[pos_val].1;
            ensure!(validator_delegator_points >= amount, "not enough delegated points");
            let points_to_remove = std::cmp::min(amount, validator_delegator_points);
            ensure!(validator_config.is_active, "validator currently inactive");
            validator_config.points =
                validator_config.points.checked_sub(&points_to_remove).ok_or("underflow")?;

            let pos_del =
                delegator_config.delegates.iter().position(|(x, _)| x == &validator).unwrap();

            let points_remaining = validator_delegator_points - points_to_remove;
            if validator_delegator_points == points_to_remove {
                validator_config.delegators.remove(pos_val);
                delegator_config.delegates.remove(pos_del);
            }

            let new_delegation_amount = delegator_config.delegated_points - points_to_remove;
            delegator_config.delegated_points = new_delegation_amount;
            T::Currency::remove_lock(LOCK_ID, &who);
            T::Currency::set_lock(LOCK_ID, &who, new_delegation_amount, WithdrawReasons::all());

            Validators::<T>::insert(validator.clone(), validator_config);
            Delegators::<T>::insert(who.clone(), delegator_config);
            Pallet::<T>::reduce_stake(amount);
            Pallet::<T>::check_candidate(validator);

            Ok(())
        }
    }

    impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
        // A function to get you an account id for the current block author.
        fn find_author() -> Option<T::AccountId> {
            let digest = frame_system::Pallet::<T>::digest();
            let pre_runtime_digests = digest.logs.iter().filter_map(|d| d.as_pre_runtime());

            for (id, mut data) in pre_runtime_digests {
                if id == AURA_ENGINE_ID {
                    let slot = Slot::decode(&mut data).ok()?;
                    let author_index = *slot % pallet_aura::Pallet::<T>::authorities().len() as u64;
                    let validators = pallet_aura::Pallet::<T>::authorities();
                    let authority = validators.get(author_index as usize).cloned()?;
                    return Some(T::AuthorityToAccount::convert(authority));
                }
            }

            None
        }

        fn get_slot() -> Option<sp_consensus_aura::Slot> {
            let digest = frame_system::Pallet::<T>::digest();
            let pre_runtime_digests = digest.logs.iter().filter_map(|d| d.as_pre_runtime());

            for (id, mut data) in pre_runtime_digests {
                if id == AURA_ENGINE_ID {
                    let slot = Slot::decode(&mut data).ok()?;
                    return Some(slot);
                }
            }

            None
        }

        fn increase_stake(amount: BalanceOf<T>) {
            let mut stake;
            match StakePool::<T>::try_get() {
                Ok(x) => {
                    stake = x;
                    stake.validators += amount;
                    StakePool::<T>::set(stake);
                },
                Err(_) => {
                    stake = TotalStake { validators: amount };
                    stake.validators = amount;
                    StakePool::<T>::set(stake);
                },
            }
        }

        fn reduce_stake(amount: BalanceOf<T>) {
            let mut stake;
            match StakePool::<T>::try_get() {
                Ok(x) => {
                    stake = x;
                    stake.validators -= amount;
                    StakePool::<T>::set(stake);
                },
                Err(_) => {
                    stake = TotalStake { validators: Default::default() };
                    StakePool::<T>::set(stake);
                },
            };
        }

        fn check_candidate(candidate: T::AccountId) -> DispatchResult {
            let mut candidates = EnabledAuthorities::<T>::get();

            match candidates {
                Some(x) => {
                    let mut candidates = x;
                    candidates.authorities.sort_by(|(_, a), (_, b)| a.partial_cmp(b).unwrap());
                    let candidate_balance =
                        Validators::<T>::get(&candidate).ok_or("not a validator")?;
                    match candidate_balance.points > candidates.authorities[0].1 {
                        true => match candidate == candidates.authorities[0].0 {
                            true => {
                                candidates.authorities[0].1 = candidate_balance.points;
                                EnabledAuthorities::<T>::set(Some(candidates));
                            },
                            false => {
                                candidates.authorities[0] = (candidate, candidate_balance.points);
                                EnabledAuthorities::<T>::set(Some(candidates));
                            },
                        },
                        false => match candidate == candidates.authorities[0].0 {
                            true => {
                                candidates.authorities[0].1 = candidate_balance.points;
                                EnabledAuthorities::<T>::set(Some(candidates));
                            },
                            false => {
                                let mut pos = candidates
                                    .authorities
                                    .iter()
                                    .position(|(x, _)| *x == candidate);
                                match pos {
                                    Some(p) => {
                                        candidates.authorities.remove(p);
                                        EnabledAuthorities::<T>::set(Some(candidates));
                                    },
                                    None => (),
                                }
                            },
                        },
                    }
                },

                None => {
                    let candidate_balance =
                        Validators::<T>::get(&candidate).ok_or("not a validator")?;
                    let mut candidates = Candidates { authorities: Default::default() };
                    let tuple = (candidate, candidate_balance.points);
                    candidates.authorities.try_push(tuple);
                    EnabledAuthorities::<T>::set(Some(candidates));
                },
            }

            Ok(())
        }

        fn register_delegator(who: T::AccountId) -> DispatchResult {
            let default_config = DelegatorConfig {
                is_validator: false,
                delegated_points: Default::default(),
                delegates: bounded_vec![],
            };

            Delegators::<T>::insert(who, default_config);

            Ok(())
        }
    }
}
```

Oh and this is the full error message:

````
warning: unused import: `frame_support::traits::tokens::Balance`
  --> pallets/dpos/src/lib.rs:22:6
   |
22 |     use frame_support::traits::tokens::Balance;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

warning: unused import: `FindAuthor`
  --> pallets/dpos/src/lib.rs:26:22
   |
26 |         traits::{Currency, FindAuthor, LockableCurrency, ReservableCurrency},
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0277]: the trait bound `<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId: pallet::Config` is not satisfied
   --> pallets/dpos/src/lib.rs:39:44
    |
39  |       #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
    |  _______________________________________________^
40  | |     pub struct Pallet<T>(_);
41  | |
42  | |     /// Configure the pallet by specifying the parameters and types on which it depends.
...   |
103 | |     #[pallet::storage]
104 | |     pub type Validators<T: Config> = StorageMap<
    | |_______________________^ the trait `pallet::Config` is not implemented for `<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId`
    |
note: required by a bound in `ValidatorConfig`
   --> pallets/dpos/src/lib.rs:78:32
    |
78  |     pub struct ValidatorConfig<T: Config, AccountId, Balance> {
    |                                   ^^^^^^ required by this bound in `ValidatorConfig`
help: consider further restricting the associated type
    |
39  |     #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store where <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId: pallet::Config)]
    |                                                     ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

error[E0277]: the trait bound `<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId: pallet::Config` is not satisfied
   --> pallets/dpos/src/lib.rs:39:44
    |
39  |       #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
    |  _______________________________________________^
40  | |     pub struct Pallet<T>(_);
41  | |
42  | |     /// Configure the pallet by specifying the parameters and types on which it depends.
...   |
111 | |     #[pallet::storage]
112 | |     pub type Delegators<T: Config> = StorageMap<
    | |_______________________^ the trait `pallet::Config` is not implemented for `<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId`
    |
note: required by a bound in `DelegatorConfig`
   --> pallets/dpos/src/lib.rs:85:32
    |
85  |     pub struct DelegatorConfig<T: Config, AccountId, Balance> {
    |                                   ^^^^^^ required by this bound in `DelegatorConfig`
help: consider further restricting the associated type
    |
39  |     #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store where <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId: pallet::Config)]
    |                                                     ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

error[E0277]: the trait bound `<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId: pallet::Config` is not satisfied
   --> pallets/dpos/src/lib.rs:39:44
    |
39  |       #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
    |  _______________________________________________^
40  | |     pub struct Pallet<T>(_);
41  | |
42  | |     /// Configure the pallet by specifying the parameters and types on which it depends.
...   |
122 | |     #[pallet::storage]
123 | |     pub type EnabledAuthorities<T: Config> =
    | |_______________________________^ the trait `pallet::Config` is not implemented for `<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId`
    |
note: required by a bound in `Candidates`
   --> pallets/dpos/src/lib.rs:99:27
    |
99  |     pub struct Candidates<T: Config, AccountId, Balance> {
    |                              ^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Candidates`
help: consider further restricting the associated type
    |
39  |     #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store where <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId: pallet::Config)]
    |                                                     ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
warning: `pallet-dpos` (lib) generated 2 warnings
error: could not compile `pallet-dpos` due to 3 previous errors; 2 warnings emitted```
Thanks
````

Answer (score 2):

You are using `DelegatorConfig<T::AccountId, BalanceOf<T>, T::MaxDelegations>` instead of `DelegatorConfig<T, T::AccountId, BalanceOf<T>>`.

Comment: Yeah, that helps but if you look at the full code I use #[derive(TypeInfo)], which doesn't let me apply your solution in particular. But it did help, thanks!

Comment: My rep doesn't allow me to vote yet, but you helped so you got a spiritual upvote from me

Answer (score 1):

So what I did was the following: addded `#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]` to the struct and modified the rest as follows:

```
    #[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
    pub struct DelegatorConfig<T: Config> {
        pub is_validator: bool,
        pub delegated_points: BalanceOf<T>,
        pub delegates: BoundedVec<(T::AccountId, BalanceOf<T>), T::MaxDelegations>,
    }
```

```
#[pallet::storage]
    pub type Delegators<T: Config> = StorageMap<
    _,
    Blake2_128Concat,
    T::AccountId,
    DelegatorConfig<T>,
    >;
```